# Solutions Deploying Status Stuck at Deploying and Retracting - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, virtual-machine, sharepoint-2013, stsadm

I have 3 tier architecture server which are 1 Web Front Ender Server (WFE), 1 Application Server (APP) and 1 Database Server (DB) that installed in 1 physical server / host. Then suddenly the host broken caused by the RAM is broken.

After that happen, we done some recovery and use the VM backup then restore it to the new host / physical server. After we restored all the Virtual Machine (WFE, APP, DB) the sharepoint running OK and then when we try to retract and deploy some solutions, the ***deployment status stucks at deploying and retracting*** whenever we tried.

We have tried to deploy and retract from Central Administration, using powershell command, and using stsadm command line but keeps getting the same result. ***Anyone having the same problem ? and how you solve this ?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I tried many things to fix the problem.

Finally I fixed the problem. All I did,

1.***Checking the Sharepoint Timer Service running on every Sharepoint Server in farm*** 
2.***Restarting the Sharepoint Timer Service (you can check the service in windows services.msc) on every Sharepoint Server (Web Front End Server and Application Server) in the farm at the same time***

Thank you guys